# On iOS only, sticky table headers come unstuck after scrolling

Tags: html, ios, css, angular, ipad

I'm creating a console screen with several data tables. All are scrollable, with sticky headers. Here's the CSS for the header row:

```
mat-header-row {
    top: 0px;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

On the desktop (Windows 10, tested with Chrome and Edge), this works as expected; the header stays visible at the top of the table when the data scrolls. But on the iPad (with both Safari and Chrome), they stay sticky only until I've scrolled past one full table viewport (i.e. if the table shows ten rows at a time, it works until I've scrolled up exactly ten rows). Then, they come unstuck and scroll off the top with the rest of the upper rows. They reappear at the same place when I scroll back down.

The client requires iPad support. I'm testing on an iPad Air 2, running iOS 12.2. Apparently earlier versions of iOS didn't fully support the sticky property, so my searches return a lot of related problems, but none of them are for this specific issue. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I tried adding "position: -webkit-sticky" as well. It doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: How about a link so I can test this?

Comment: @AndyHoffman I'll try to set one up when I get to work tomorrow. What's a good, free way to host a simple web page these days? It's for intranet use, so I don't have work access to an outside server.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Unfortunately it appears to be a known and unfixed issue with Angular Material running on iOS. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12044